# What command can you use to quickly find which file on your home folder containing the umask command?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, umask

What command can you use to quickly find which file on your home folder containing the umask command?

```
$ grep -rnw "umask" ~
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "containing umask command"? You mean with the default permission set by `umask`? By default it'd be `umask 022`, resulting in file permissions 755.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern in `grep` is placed in front of the file/path:

> grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]

To receive just the matching filenames instead of the matches, you should use `-l` option:

```
grep -rlw "umask" ~
```

If you want all matches of all files including their line number, you need to use `-n` instead of `-l`:

```
grep -rnw "umask" ~
```